# positioning issue on iOS

Tags: ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jquery mobile-1.2.0 and cordova-2.1.0 for my iOS app. Everything is working fine on iOS simulator, but if I run the app on iPhone, then when I go to the specific page, the content below the header comes up and then set to its defined position. Why is this happening?

From login.htm page I go to the menu.htm using `$.mobile.changePage('menu.htm', {transition: "slide"});` and below is the menu.htm:

```
<div data-role="content">    
    <ul data-role="listview" id="mainMenu">        
        <li style="height:50px">            
            <a href="LeadScreens/leadHome.htm" data-transition="slide" id="leadsLink">                
                <img src="images/leads.png" alt="leads" class="ui-li-icon"/>
                Leads                
            </a>            
        </li>        
        <li style="height:50px">            
            <a href="abc.htm" data-transition="slide" id="activitiesLink">                
                <img src="images/activities.jpg" alt="activities" class="ui-li-icon"/>
                Activities                
            </a>            
        </li>        
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: would be nice if u could post some code here..

Comment: From login.htm page I go to the menu.htm using                 $.mobile.changePage('menu.htm', {transition: "slide"});
and below is the menu.htm <div data-role="content"><ul data-role="listview" id="mainMenu"><li style="height:50px"><a href="LeadScreens/leadHome.htm" data-transition="slide" id="leadsLink"><img src="images/leads.png" alt="leads" class="ui-li-icon"/>Leads</a></li><li style="height:50px"><a href="abc.htm" data-transition="slide" id="activitiesLink"><img src="images/activities.jpg" alt="activities" class="ui-li-icon"/>Activities</a></li></ul></div></div>

Comment: are u giving the <div data-role="page" id="id" data-theme="">
 <div id="header" data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="" data-position=""></div></div> in the menu.htm mark-up?

Comment: I am using like this in menu.htm<div data-role="page" id="menuPage">
<div id="headDiv" data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div></div>

Comment: Exactly how are you expecting it to look, and how does it actually look? Please explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `</div>` there at the bottom. That could be the problem.

Comment: @ Justin no that </div> is not the problem .actually that </div> is page div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vXv4w/4 this is login.htm and after button click I am refer to the http://jsfiddle.net/WNvB4/1 which is menu.htm using slide transition.while sliding from login.htm to menu.htm half part of list item 'Menu 1' goes below  the 'header' and then comes up to the original position.

Comment: This issue is because of header height.I have fixed the height of header,if I remove fixed height then this issue will not appear but I want to increase the height of header how to do?